# watching courses react native expo and react-native cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I have knowledge about react native with cli, while in most of the courses they used react native with expo, my question is that , can i follow a course while i am using react native with cli? are there big differences between them ?

Answer (score 0):

For beginners, I would recommend going with Expo since it will take a lot of your headache away, and later, when you are more familiar with the React environment, you can always eject from Expo to Bareflow, which works similar to the React-Native CLI but comes under Expo.

In my opinion, React-Native CLI gives you more freedom, liberty, and control to express and experiment over your code whereas, Expo binds you in a shell where you rely more on Expo dependencies. The choice is yours depending on your level of the React expertise.
hope you got your answer